Problems with Webpack and React
i am fighting with webpack since quite some time now. Basically i am trying to get it to run with my React Application.
My rough folder structure is:
-
|__ public/
    |__ index.html
|__ src/
    |__ App.js
    |__ index.js
    |___ ....
|___ .babelrc
|___ webpack.config.js

My webpack config looks like this:
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')

const isDevelopment = process.env.MODE !== 'production';

console.log(`isDev: ${isDevelopment}`)

module.exports = {
    mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    stats: 'minimal',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|less|css)$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif)?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
          }),
    ],
    devServer: { 
        hot: false, // disable hot reloading temporarily 
        port: 9000, 
        open: true, 
    },
}

This is how my index.js looks like:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>);

This is the .babelrc:
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env", 
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
  

This is the index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


I tried alot of iterations on the config and none of them worked. Currently have a white screen and a js error on the console:
bootstrap:19 Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_modules__[moduleId].call is not a function
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js (xhr.js:197:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/utils/APIHandler.js (Writeups.js:80:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/components/contact/index.js (App.js:62:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/pages/home/Home.js (EditWriteup.js:154:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at ./src/App.js (svg-injector.esm.js:317:1)


Can you provide the code repo?
